# The case $x < - 3$ in the absolute value equation $|x + 3| + |x - 2| = 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

In the absolute value equation $|x + 3| + |x - 2| = 5$, why do we replace $|x + 3|$ by $-x - 3$ rather than $3 - x$ when $-\infty < x < -3$?

[image: absolute_value_equation_case]

> $$|x+3|+|x-2|=5$$
>   What is the result set?
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
>     & \hphantom{xxx}-3 & \hphantom{xxx-2} & 2\hphantom{-xxx} \\\hline
> x+3 & - & + & + \\\hline
> x-2 & - & - & +
> \end{array}$$
>
> My problem is in the case $-\infty<x<3$.
>   $-\infty<x<3$ $\implies$ $-x-3-x-2=5$ $\implies$ $-2x-1=5$ $\implies$ $-2x=6$ $\implies$ $x=-3$
>   As a basic rule in absolute value we can change $|x+3|$ to $3-x$ when $x<0$ and we want to remove the absolute value.
>   So that why we didn't solve it like:
>   $3-x+2-x=-5$ $\implies$ $-2x=0$ $\implies$ $x=0$ and $x$ is inacceptable

Comment: In general, you must change $|y|$ by $-y$ when $y<0$. In this particular case, you must change $|x+3|$ by $-(x+3)$ when $x+3<0$, which is the same as saying that you change $|x+3$ by $-x-3$ when $x<-3$.

Comment: As an aside, this website uses MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to format mathematics.  Often times, it is as simple as just enclosing the formula in \$ signs, but gives us access to many more complicated ways of displaying mathematical symbols and equations.  [See here for a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to use MathJax on the site.  It is preferred that you type your questions instead of using pictures of text/formulas so that it can be searched for in the future.

Comment: @JMoravitz --  Does searching really work with mathematical formulae?? If it doesn't, then LaTeX doesn't provide any benefit over tidy handwriting and drawing. It certainly doesn't provide any more flexibility than a pen and paper.

Comment: @bubba yes, actually, searching **does** work with mathematical formulae.  The dollar signs are still just part of the text according to the search engines.  I suggest you try it out with some simple examples that don't require much knowledge of LaTeX, and perhaps more complicated examples later.  [for example this](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%229%2C+99%2C+999%2C+9999%2C+99999%22) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22\sum_{n%3D1}^{\infty}+\frac{\sin%28+\frac{-5}{n^2}%29}{n^2}%22).

Answer (score 4):

Reminders about absolute value:

$$|x|:=\begin{cases} x&\text{when}~x\geq 0\\ -x&\text{when}~x<0\end{cases}$$

For your specific question, finding the values of $x$ such that $|x+3|+|x-2|=5$, it behooves us to break into cases so that we may remove the absolute value signs.

$|x+3|+|x-2| = \begin{cases} x+3+x-2&\text{when}~x\geq 2\\
x+3-x+2&\text{when}~-3<x<2\\
-x-3-x+2&\text{when}~x\leq -3\end{cases}$

Setting the expression equal to five gives us for the first case, $x\geq 2$ and $2x+1=5\Rightarrow 2x=4\Rightarrow x=2$.  Checking, $x=2$ does agree with $x\geq 2$ so it is a solution.  Indeed $|x+3|+|x-2|=|2+3|+|2-2|=|5|+|0|=5$

For the second case, we get $x+3-x+2$ which is equal to five *always* regardless the value of $x$, so all values in the second case will work.  For example, $x=0.1$, we have $|0.1+3|+|0.1-2|=|3.1|+|-1.9|=3.1+1.9=5$

For the third case, we get $x\leq -3$ and $-x-3-x+2=5\Rightarrow -2x-1=5\Rightarrow -2x=6\Rightarrow x=-3$.  Checking, $x=-3$ does agree with $x\leq -3$ so it is also a solution.

Putting all of this together, we have the full solution set is the set of all numbers $x$ such that $-3\leq x\leq 2$  (or using interval notation, $[-3,2]$)

In your work, you say something along the lines of "When $x<0$ we can change $|3+x|$ to $|3-x|$."  That is not true.  Take $x=-1$ for counterexample.  $|3+(-1)|=|2|=2$ whereas $|3-(-1)|=|3+1|=|4|=4$.  Refer again to the definition of absolute value given above.  It says that **if whatever is in the absolute value as a whole** is negative, then change its sign.  You do not change the sign of single pieces of what is in it.

$$|3+x|=\begin{cases}3+x&\text{when}~3+x\geq 0\\ -(3+x)&\text{when}~3+x<0\end{cases}$$